# Google Cloud - Connect Sql Server to Google Apps Script

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mssql-jdbc

I have problems to connect **sql server on google cloud** to google apps script, have tried many options do url connection like: Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://apis-para-pap:southamerica-east1:revistamarcasserver","sqlserver", "*****"); but is not connecting, Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string.
Do you can help me to solve this problem to **connect Sql Server to Google Apps Script**?

Information about google cloud Sql Server:

- DB Type: SQL Server 2017 Standard
- Location: southamerica-east1-b
- Instance name: apis-para-pap:southamerica-east1:revistamarcasserver
- Public address: 34.95.157.142
- White list: (72.14.192.0/18) (64.233.160.0/19) (209.85.128.0/17) (66.102.0.0/20) (74.125.0.0/16) (173.194.0.0/16) (66.249.80.0/20) (64.18.0.0/20) (216.239.32.0/19) (207.126.144.0/20)

(observation: Using sql server management studio, i have tested and connected successfully, with this informations).

**Thank you so much**

Comment: Are you passing user credentials to access the database? As in Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(connectionString, username, password). Be sure you do not use the 'root' user and password to access the database. Create a dedicated user in Google Cloud console. Check the connection string for your mysql instance. Append '/mydatabasename' to the connection string. Also, not connecting could be a thousand different things. Please post all error messages and your code (without personal information).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help Anton Dementiev this is very important to me. Yes, I'm putting the credentials as an example:
Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection ("jdbc: google: mysql: // apis-to-pap: southamerica-east1: magazinemarkederver", "sqlserver", "*****");
"Error: Failed to establish a connection to the database. Check connection string, username and password."
A part of the login password is correct as I have already tested it in sql server management studio.

Comment: Again, try connecting not as a root user. Also, what database are you connecting to? Please append it to the end of your string. I had the same issue with my MySQL Google database that was resolved by creating another user and connecting directly to the DB. You can create a database on your instance via Google cloud shell or console UI

Comment: Follow this example and put in the DB name https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/service/jdbc.gs

Comment: Thanks for repply Anton Dementiev, I have followed the tutorial that you shared, created a new user, database, and append into the url string connection:
Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://apis-para-pap:southamerica-east1:revistamarcasserver/SGBDMARCAS","adm", "*****");
But the same error have ocurred.
Maybe is an bug for connecting cloud sql server into google apps script?

Comment: Have you [whitelisted the Google IP ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#using_jdbcgetconnectionurl) ?

Comment: Try changing the default Google Cloud Project of your Apps Script to your SQL instance project (so that both of them are part of the same GCP project)

Comment: @ZektorH thanks for helping me, I whitelisted all this ips: 
(72.14.192.0/18)
(64.233.160.0/19)
(209.85.128.0/17)
(66.102.0.0/20)
(74.125.0.0/16)
(173.194.0.0/16)
(66.249.80.0/20)
(64.18.0.0/20)
(216.239.32.0/19)
(207.126.144.0/20)
But the error continues...

Comment: @Anton Dementiev Hello, thanks for repply again I appreciate, do you know some tutorial to do this? "changing the default Google Cloud Project of your Apps Script to your SQL instance", I'm searching on google but didn't find how

Comment: To change the default GCP project, use this [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).

Comment: @ZektorH thanks a lot for shared the tutorial, I followed all the steps and associate my google cloud platform to google apps script but Unfortunately the problem persist.

Comment: Please check the new answer and let us know if that solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance), [authorize the following IP ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) and was able to connect to it using the Public Ip Address. I could not connect using Instance connection name.

```
var db = 'mydatabase';
var instanceUrl = "jdbc:mysql://Public_IP_address_SQL";
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

/**
* Create a new database within a Cloud SQL instance.

*/
function createDatabase() {
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(instanceUrl,{user: 'root', password: '****'} );
conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + db);
}

/**
* Create a new user for your database with full privileges.
*/
function createUser() {
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl,{user: 'root', password: '****'});

var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?');
stmt.setString(1, user);
stmt.setString(2, userPwd);
stmt.execute();

conn.createStatement().execute('GRANT ALL ON `%`.* TO ' + user);
}

/**
* Create a new table in the database.
*/
function createTable() {
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, {user: 'new_user', password: '****'});
conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE TABLE entries '
    + '(guestName VARCHAR(255), content VARCHAR(255), '
    + 'entryID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(entryID));');
}


createDatabase()
createUser() 
createTable()

}
```

Comment: Not working for SQL Server intence, but thanks for help marian.vladoi